# Wrong regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex, winforms

I have this string input in C#:

```
string InputNames = "\"James Alkaba\", \"Carl James\", \"Thomas Merk\"";
```

I want to use a regular expression to make this string look like:
`James Alkaba,Carl James,Thomas Merk`.
Basically to get rid of the "" and the space after the `,`.

I have tried this one:

```
\s*""([^""]+)"""
```

but it didn't seem to work.

The code (not using regex right now, but I figured that using it might be the best solution):

```
public static string[] GetListOfUsers()
{
   // String InputNames is loaded from a tool and it contains text "James Alkaba", "Carl James", "Thomas Merk" including the " symbol

   string[] names = InputNames.Split(new char[] { ',', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

   return names;
}
```

I'm trying to list the returned array in a combo box:

```
string[] users = Common.GetListOfUsers();
cmbOwner.Items.AddRange(users);
```

So when I open the combo box, it will just list all the names.

Comment: Showing us your pattern doesn't help - we need to see how you're using the `Regex` class.

Comment: Please post the code that you used to actually perform the transformation.

Comment: And also provide valid source string example

Comment: You don't really *have* to use a regEx for that, you can use a simple replace instead

Comment: What's the *real* input? A CSV file with quoted text fields perhaps? This is a perfectly valid and standard-compliant CSV row, it doesn't need any conversions. A CSV parser like CsvHelper can easily handle this, without using regular expressions.

Comment: Why not doing simply  yourString.Replace("\"\"", "");

Comment: Removing the quotes may be a *bad* idea, if one of those fields contains a comma. `"James, Alkaba", "Carl James"` is a 2-field CSV row. If you remove the quotes you get `James, Alkaba,Carl James`, 3 fields.

Comment: @Ghassen I get the "cannot implicitly convert type string to string[]" error

Comment: yes beacause you updated your question :D

Comment: return names .Select( n => n.Replace("\"\"", "")).ToArray();

Comment: Use `Regex.Replace(InputNames, "\s?\"", "");`

Comment: You could split on `,` and use [string.Trim()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=net-7.0#system-string-trim(system-char())) to tidy the ends.

Comment: This question is eerily similar to [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77222108). Is this, for example, a homework question and you are classmates or these accounts belong to the same person?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that names don't have `"` you can use

```
"(?<text>[^"]+)"
```

pattern and match for a *group* with `text` name, for instance

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

string source = @"""James Alkaba"", ""Carl James"", ""Thomas Merk""";

string result = string.Join(",", Regex
  .Matches(source, @"""(?<text>[^""]+)""")
  .Cast<Match>() // <- may be dropped in late c# versions
  .Select(match => match.Groups["text"].Value));

Console.Write(result);
```

Output

```
James Alkaba,Carl James,Thomas Merk
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6jKUvr)

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comments, you need simply to use the *String.Replace* method.

So your method will be like this:

```
public static string[] GetListOfUsers()
{
   // String InputNames is loaded from a tool and it contains text "James Alkaba", "Carl James", "Thomas Merk" including the " symbol

   string[] names = InputNames.Split(new char[] { ',', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

   return names.Select(n => n.Replace("\"\"", "")).ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I can think of is just:

```
string input = "\"James Alkaba\" , \"Carl James\", \"Thomas Merk\"";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(input, "\"(.+?)\"\\s*(,|$)\\s*", "$1$2"));
```

Where:

- `\"(.+?)\"` - capture everything in quotes (non-greedy) as `$1`,
- `\\s*` - non-captured spaces before comma (or the end of string),
- `(,|$)` - capture comma or the end of string as `$2`,
- `\\s*` - non-captured spaces after comma (or the end of string).

Output:

```
James Alkaba,Carl James,Thomas Merk
```

Comment: This one worked perfectly and I am very thankful sir :)

Answer (score 1):

What if, just for a second, forget about quotes or commas or something else but letters and create a pattern to lookup for 2 groups of letters, separated by space?

For example,
`@"[A-Za-z]+\s{1}[A-Za-z]+"`, where:

- `[A-Za-z]+` - first group of letters which are Firstname
- `\s{1}` - single space separator
- `[A-Za-z]+` - second group of letters which are Lastname

Usage:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
// ...

string inputNames = "\"James Alkaba\", \"Carl James\", \"Thomas Merk\"";
var names = Regex.Matches(inputNames, @"[A-Za-z]+\s{1}[A-Za-z]+")
                 .OfType<Match>()
                 .Select(match => match.Value); // optionally, ...Value.Trim()
                 //.ToArray(); or .ToList(); or skip, if it's not neccessary to evaluate

// Output:
// [0] James Alkaba
// [1] Carl James
// [2] Thomas Merk

// And append to Combobox: 
cmbOwner.Items.AddRange(names);
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't require regex and would be easier without it. Just simply use `.Replace()` to remove the , ", and . For example,

```
string InputNames = "\"James Alkaba\", \"Carl James\", \"Thomas Merk\"";
string output = InputNames.Replace("\\", "").Replace("\"", "").Replace(", ", ",");
```

`output` = `"James Alkaba,Carl James,Thomas Merk"`